# For-loop with boolean instead of variable initialization

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, boolean

I've got this code fragment:

```
private static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;

    for (test('1'); test('2') && (x <= 2); test('3'))
    {
        x++;
        test('4');
    }

    System.out.println(" Counter=" + counter);
}

static boolean test(char num)
{
    System.out.print(" " + num);
    counter++;
    return true;
}
```

Why does the `for`loop doing here? I thought that the first statement in a for loop has to be  the initialization of a variable and that this will not compile, but it runs and puts the output:

```
 1 2 4 3 2 4 3 2 Counter=8
```

What is the `boolean` doing here?

Comment: The `for` *initialization* expression doesn't have to be a variable assignment; it can do whatever is necessary. Even `for(;;)` is valid.

Comment: because the conditions evaluate to `True`, so the loop runs.

Comment: `for(pre-statement;boolean;post-statement)` is what for loop is for.

Comment: Note that the results of `test('1')` and `test('3')` will be thrown out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "initialization" statement (`test('1')` in this case) can be any *statement list* (see the JLS link below); it does not need to actually be an initialization.

The condition `test('2') && (x <= 2)` will be evaluated before every loop iteration as per usual until it becomes false. The increment, `test('3')` will be executed after each iteration.

This is detailed in [JLS §14.14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1).

---

Let's walk through it by hand:

1. First iteration:

   - `test(1)` called

     - `1` printed and `counter` set to `1`
   - Condition `test('2') && (x <= 2)` executed

     - `2` printed and `counter` set to `2`
     - Condition returns `true`
   - `x++`: `x` set to `2`
   - `test(4)` called

     - `4` printed and `counter` set to `3`
   - Increment `test('3')` called

     - `3` printed and `counter` set to `4`
2. Second iteration:

   - Condition `test('2') && (x <= 2)` executed

     - `2` printed and `counter` set to `5`
     - Condition returns `true`
   - `x++`: `x` set to `3`
   - `test(4)` called

     - `4` printed and `counter` set to `6`
   - Increment `test('3')` called

     - `3` printed and `counter` set to `7`
3. Third iteration:

   - Condition `test('2') && (x <= 2)` executed

     - `2` printed and `counter` set to `8`
     - Condition returns `false`, since `x` is now 3

Comment: Not "any single statement".  It's a statement list.  The doc you linked (the right one, of course), says that `ForInit` (which is optional) can be a `StatementExpressionList`, which is one or more `StatementExpression`s separated by commas.  The same thing for `ForUpdate`.  So OP's code could even have been `for (test('1'), test('2'); test('3') && (x <= 2); test('4'), test('5') ) { /* … */ }`.  Aside from that omission, this answer is right.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted. :)  It's still a little bit imprecise though:  I'm not sure that there's such a thing as a "blank statement list".  The `ForInit` is _optional_.  It's it's provided, it's _either_ a `LocalVariableDeclaration` _or_ a `StatementExpressionList`.  A `StatementExpressionList` has at least  one `StatementExpression`.  A case like `for ( ; …; …) { … }` doesn't have a _blank_ statement expression list, it just doesn't provide a `ForInit`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, I think you're right. The bit about the blank statement made more sense in the context of my original post; I'll edit once more. I just saw that the `ForInit` is optional in the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid for loop so it works OK.

It has (initialization, termination, increment) parts.

These three can be just about any valid expressions (almost).
1) The **termination** needs to be **boolean**
2) The **initialization** and **increment** can be any **expression list**

Here is an informal description of the for loop syntax.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

For a more formal description check the JLS.

Comment: This isn't correct.  [The spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) describes the syntax.  The first part (if provided) is _either_ a `LocalVariableDeclaration` (which isn't an expression) or a `StatementExpressionList` (one or more statements separated (if more than one) with commas)).  The third is another `StatementExpressionList`.  The second, though, must be an expression, and _must_ be a `boolean` or `Boolean` values expression.  It can't be "any valid expression".

Comment: @brunch875 You _can't_ do `while(5) { /* … */ }` in Java;  it's a "cannot convert from int to boolean" compile error.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor His point was that you can simulate it with a for loop (like this for(;5;) {...}) This is how I got it. But that does not compile too. OK, well, fair enough.

Comment: @peter.petrov The link provided doesn't seem to provide a general syntax for `for` loops, though.  It just seems to give an informal description of how they're used…